# Can't seem to figure out a way to print certain objects from a function containing a loop

Tags: r, function, loops

I have the following code:

```
calculations <- function(data,id)
{
by(dataset, dataset$id, function(x) 
{
  if(nrow(x) == 1L) 
  {
    return(c(mean(x$Var1),mean(x$Var2),
          ("Cannot take standard deviation, number of observations is equal to 1")))
  }
  else
  {
    return(c(mean(x$Var1), mean(x$Var2), sd(x$Var1), sd(x$Var2)))
  }})
}
```

that prints out the following output:

```
dataset$id: 1
[1] 0.3961182 3.8605641 1.0251303 2.6779033
-------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
dataset$id: 2
[1] 0.1656521 3.7565732 0.8687900 2.2305298
-------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
dataset$id: 3
[1] -0.3831954  4.0803145  1.3875692  2.1146944
-------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
dataset$id: 4
[1] 0.6719857 4.7523648 0.2001029 1.3715562
-------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
dataset$id: 5
[1] 0.01666328 3.18141270 0.98473329 1.76379804
-------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
dataset$id: 6
[1] 0.2542346 4.6464406 1.1077001 2.4604031
-------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
dataset$id: 7
[1] "-0.182601790360647"                                                  
[2] "5.67379078955704"                                                    
[3] "Cannot take standard deviation, number of observations is equal to 1"
-------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
dataset$id: 8
[1] 0.293840 4.669857 1.116413 2.712787
```

This output goes all the way up to 40. I want to find a way to print out only certain lines of code but I can't seem to figure out how. For example say I only want to print out the line dataset$id: 3 then the output I want would be:

```
dataset$id: 3
[1] -0.3831954  4.0803145  1.3875692  2.1146944
```

Also, when I try and type in:

```
> calculations(dataset, 3)
```

after my function calculations, it just keeps printing my entire loop and I feel like it shouldn't be doing that. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Could you give a small sample data frame? You probably don't want to use `dataset$id` inside your functions where `id` is an argument... use `dataset[, id]` instead if you want the code to be dynamic based on the value of `id` passed into the function.

Comment: Also, is printing really your goal? Most people find returned output more useful. It would be very easy, for example, to create a summary data frame that has the means and the standard deviations (NA if a single value) for each id. Then if you only want to see id=3, all you have to do is look at the 3rd line.

Comment: your function has an argument data that you do not use ; instead, you use dataset, which is not defined